# How to fix JxBrowser 6.12 scaling outside its boundaries in JavaFX 8 on Windows 10 64-bit?

Tags: java, windows, javafx, javafx-8, jxbrowser

Since switching from JxBrowser 6.11.1 to 6.12, I'm having scaling problems with our JavaFX 8 application on Windows (10, 64-bit). Mac and Linux render fine. The Browser goes outside the BrowserView boundaries, and covers the UI controls on the bottom and on the right.

I've published a proof-of-concept (with included screenshots of the problem) at https://github.com/dwagelaar/be.healthconnect.jxbrowserscaling. [jxbrowser-6.11.1.png](https://github.com/dwagelaar/be.healthconnect.jxbrowserscaling/blob/master/jxbrowser-6.11.1.png) displays what should be visible (button bar at the bottom), and [jxbrowser-6.12.png](https://github.com/dwagelaar/be.healthconnect.jxbrowserscaling/blob/master/jxbrowser-6.12.png) shows the problem I have.

Is this a bug in JxBrowser or my code (see [App.java](https://github.com/dwagelaar/be.healthconnect.jxbrowserscaling/blob/master/src/main/java/be/healthconnect/be/healthconnect/jxbrowserscaling/App.java))?

Comment: This is an issue in 6.12 that is reproducible on Windows 10 with HiDPI displays. We have already started working on this issue. We figured out what causes it and right now we are working on the fix. I will post an answer when we publish updated build with the fix.

Comment: Just tested with 6.13-b5-eap, but there was no difference with 6.12 yet.

Comment: I checked your example on Windows 10 64-bit with 6.13-b5-eap build. The issue isn't reproducible. Could you please make sure that you see the issue with your example you put on GitHub and 6.13-b5-eap build.